# Set item to has all free space width

Tags: css

I have following HTML snippet:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">Left block</div>

  <input type="text" />

  <div id="right">Some longer than 200px text</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#right {
  min-width: 200px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
input {
  float: left;
}
```

Is it possible to set `input` to has all free space width ? I mean it should starts with `#left` right border and ends with `#right` left border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/fbVdp/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Left block</div>
    <div id="right">Some longer than 200px text</div>
    <span><input type="text" value="hello" /></span>
</div>
```

```css
​#container span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#container span input {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}​

#container {
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#right {
  min-width: 200px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with additional `div`:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">Left block</div>

  <div id="right">Some longer than 200px text</div>
</div>
<div id="main">    
  <input type="text" />
</div>​

#container {
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#right {
  min-width: 200px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#main {
    margin: 0 210px 0 210px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQevQ/

Comment: It doesn't work if `#right` has more text than `200px`. I have updated your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Flex-box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/):

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    display: -o-box;
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
}
input {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-box-flex: 1;
    -o-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -o-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4zYF/19/)

Works in all major browsers besides IE - [Support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Comment: Ok, but if I do not know the `#right` element's width ? I can't use `400px` then.

Comment: I overlooked that. I'll try to adapt it.

Comment: @hsz Edited my answer which now works with variable div sizes. Will prefix it for other browsers now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution-

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XyWre/5/) (*updated*)

jQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var w = parseInt($('#container').outerWidth()) - (parseInt($('#right').outerWidth()) + parseInt($('#left').outerWidth()));
  $('#in').css({
    border: '1px solid', //to override chrome's default- 2px inset
    width: w - 2
   });
});​
```

Comment: Updated the reason. Thats because the border 1px values should also be calculated while calculation

Comment: FYI: To measuer item's width with its border, etc you can use `.outerWidth(true)`.

Comment: Oh thanks for the info! Fiddle updated. Now it should be a good solution.

Comment: @hsz There was an issue with the previous code in chrome. I have updated it now that should work fine.